# How to chain XSLT processors in Java?

Tags: java, xslt

I'd like to perform chained XML processing with several XSLT transformers in Java. The first transformer takes the input as a `javax.xml.transform.Source` and produces a `javax.xml.transform.Result`. Not I'd like to use the result as the input for the next transformation. I.e. I need the source for the second transformation.

How is it possible to create a `Source` from a `Result` (if it's possible at all)? Or is there some other solution for what I'd like to do?

Comment: If memory serves, isn't the input to a Transform XML?  And isn't the output from a Transform also XML?  Couldn't you just take the XML from the `Result` object, and assign it to the next `Source` object?

Comment: Create the second XSLT as a SAX TransformerHandler and feed it as a SaxResult to the first Transformer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to set up the second transformation as a Sax `TransformerHandler` being the ContentHandler of the `SAXResult` of the first `Transformer` e.g.:

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    String xslt1 = "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'><xsl:template match='/'><xsl:call-template name='identity'/><xsl:comment>sheet 1</xsl:comment></xsl:template><xsl:template name='identity' match='@* | node()'><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/></xsl:copy></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";

    String xslt2 = "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'><xsl:template match='/'><xsl:call-template name='identity'/><xsl:comment>sheet 2</xsl:comment></xsl:template><xsl:template name='identity' match='@* | node()'><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/></xsl:copy></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";

    Transformer transformer1 = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt1)));

    TransformerHandler transformer2 = ((SAXTransformerFactory)transformerFactory).newTransformerHandler(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt2)));
    transformer2.setResult(new StreamResult(System.out));
    
    transformer1.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<root><item>a</item><item>b</item></root>")), new SAXResult(transformer2));
```

Or you can chain XSLT transformations as SAX `XMLFilter`s: https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/samples/java/he/JAXPExamples.java#L694

Comment: Very cool, thank you! This way it's possible to chain an arbitrary number of XSL processessors. Just add SAXResult to the chain! The only thing I don't quite like is the downcast to `SAXTransformerFactory`. Can we always be sure that we get an instance of it?

Comment: @fml2, I think you can check first whether that feature is supported, I will need to look at the API spec to spell that out, perhaps look yourself at https://github.com/apache/xalan-java/blob/master/samples/Pipe/Pipe.java#L55

Comment: I think I can just check whether `transformerFactory instanceof SAXTransformerFactory` and, if not, use serialization to strings. I hope this will never happen.

Comment: @fml2, I don't know all the different Java JREs and JDKs (Oracle, IBM, others?) and their built-in XSLT TransformerFactory implementations well enough to tell whether you can expect SAXTransformerFactory to be supported, I think Xalan does and Saxon does it as well.